# Firebase deploy fails with different errors

Tags: deployment, firebase

I get different error messages every time I try to deploy my ~700MB angular app to firebase hosting with firebase-tools.

It progresses something between 10-30% and comes up randomly with different errors like:

- Deploy Error - Storage error
- Deploy Error - Request timed out
- Deploy Error - Socket hang up

I've got node 0.10+, tried with two machines (both Windows 7, using cmder shell). Tried both "firebase init" to an existing directory and "firebase bootstrap" to an empty one and copied my files over but issues persist.

I've also made sure there are no href or src attributes with expressions in them as some other guy had issues with those.

Am I doing something wrong and is there some more enlightening log-file to read to understand what actually fails?

Comment: If you're still seeing issues, please reach out to support@firebase.com

Comment: Will do, let's see if I'll get a proper response I'll update the question with it.